# MVC & Linq: Joining multiple tables with strongly includes and passing to view/model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I can't find it clearly answered anywhere. I want to join 3 tables 2 of which aren't directly related.

- Ship > [Id] [Name]
- Itinerary > [Id] [ShipId] [Name] [StartDate] [EndDate]
- ItineraryPorts > [Id] [ItineraryId] [DayNumber] [Port]

The EF/Model class for Ship has a navigation property for Itinerary and Itinerary for ItineraryPorts.

1. What is the syntax for a strongly typed include that eager loads all Ship, Itinerary and ItineraryPorts data in one go? I want to start from the Ship table (not Itinerary).

   ```
   Ship ship = repository.Ships
      .Include(s => s.Itinerary)
      // What now?
   ```
2. Can I pass the results to the view as a Ship model? ie Can I drill down to the ItineraryPort data through the Itinerary table? Or do I need a view model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
Ship ship = repository.Ships.Include(s => s.Itinerary.Select(it => it.ItineraryPorts))
```

You don't need a specific view model for your view because all the data you need can be found through the Ship model.